# SQL unit test of stored procedure using INSERT/SELECT INTO syntax not supported

Tags: sql-server-data-tools, vs-unit-testing-framework

I'm having trouble using some of the rarer/newer `INSERT/SELECT INTO` syntax.
They run just fine from a SQL script from VS2015 + SSDT, but not within a SQL unit-test.

In all cases I am populating a temp table and using SQL Server 2012.

This standard syntax works just fine in both a SQL unit test and as a SQL script:

```
INSERT INTO #Expect ([Name], [System_Type_Name])  
VALUES ('Mail_Option', 'Varchar(20)')
```

However, these will NOT work in a unit test but if you copy-n-paste into a script they work fine:

```
SELECT * 
INTO #Actual 
FROM OPENROWSET('sqlncli', 'server=xxx;Trusted_Connection=yes;','EXEC xxx'*)
```

or

```
INSERT INTO #Actual 
    EXEC dbo.Xxx
```

The error I get is:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near the word 'INTO'.

So it's as if SQL unit tests are running differently than SQL scripts in Visual Studio.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2015** version - we have 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017 and 2019 - take your pick

Comment: That's not the answer to your question, but: 1) consider of using community standard framework for unit testing - tSQLt; 2) using OPENROWSET in unit test is something you probably shouldn't do. Unit test normally should not connect to external services

Comment: My typo-o Marc_S - it's MSSQL 2012.

Dimitrij, I actually wrote the unit-tests in tSQLt using INSERT...EXEC originally and am try to port them to the management required industry standard set by Microsoft and tried OPENROWSET as an alternative.